# Decompress .zone.gz file

Tags: zip, gzip

I have a file names `xyz.zone.gz` opening it up via `gunzip` gave me an error

```
gzip: /home/User/Downloads/xyz.zone.gz: not in gzip format
```

Earlier, I thought that the its a `.gz` file but since it gave me an error I am confused. I have never opened these type of files nor can I find information about this on google
Can anybody help me please?

EDIT:

xyz does not as well support this

[image]

Comment: Run `file /home/User/Downloads/xyz.zone.gz` and show the output.

Comment: Yes @N0rbert let me do that again

Comment: Please check , I made edits in the answer

Comment: Plwase run the command tht @N0rbert write in the first comment !!

Comment: I removed .zone as it maybe a reason for the error. Running the file with ‘xyz.zone.gz’ is no special case. Gives the same error @SorenA

Comment: Run exact command `file /home/kirti/{Documents,Downloads}/xyz*gz` and show its output please. It will give the real file-type. After this we can determine which command to use to view or unpack the file.

Comment: Try `tar xvf xyz.gz`. Sometimes files are compressed / archived inexpertly and the suffix used is incorrect; tar is usually clever enough to work it out though...